# Java XML Parsing Standards

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Has anyone ever done any type of XML paring with elements that have dashes in the names?  I don't think its possible, any ideas?

```
<Person-Response>
   <First-Name> 3119043033121014002</First-Name>
   <Last-Name> 3119043033121014002</Last-Name>
</Person-Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a questin regarding XML to java mapping then JAXB can handle it:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Person-Response")
public class PersonResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "First-Name")
    String firstName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Last-Name")
    String lastName;
}
```

Comment: Hi Norrman, I'm getting an xml string and I need to turn it into the entity you outlined above.  I didn't know of a way with JAXB to convert from an XML String to an Object without a schema.  Do you have an example to do as much?  Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Study the documentation of javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext. You can create a JAXBContext with reference to a set of annotated classes, and then create an Unmarshaller from that context.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the dashes, see the official [XML recommendation of the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/):

> Document authors are encouraged to use
>   names which are meaningful words or
>   combinations of words in natural
>   languages, and to avoid symbolic or
>   white space characters in names. Note
>   that COLON, HYPHEN-MINUS, FULL STOP
>   (period), LOW LINE (underscore), and
>   MIDDLE DOT are explicitly permitted.

Answer (score 2):

This is legal XML; any compliant parser should have no problems with it.

Comment: It is, in fact, not legal. Note the trailing 't' in the closing tag, which might be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem because of the dashes. But it is an invalid xml as per the reason mentioned by Per Norman

Comment: how would you parse something like this to a java object and get the values out?

Answer (score 0):

It is a legal XML and any parser could parse it.

Regarding Java, you have the JAXP API support for parsing this XML in either DOM, SAX or StAX.